# Proof for the NP-hardness of the Max-3-DCC Problem

Tags: reference-request, combinatorial-optimization, np

The Max-3-DCC is the variant of [vertex cycle cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cycle_cover)  problem where each of the vertex disjoint oriented cycles consists of at least 3 arcs and every vertex belongs to exactly one of those cycles; furthermore the sum of cycle edge's weight is maximal.

while I could find statements about the complexity and approximability of the problem, e.g. [here](http://wwwhome.math.utwente.nl/~mantheyb/conferences/APPROX2002_BlaeserManthey_3CycleCovers.pdf), I could not find any information about the origin of the problem or the original proof of its NP-hardness.

> **Questions:**
>
> - what is the origin of the Max-3-DCC problem?
> - where can I find the original proof of its NP-hardness?
> - are there any benchmark instances available?

Comment: Theorem 1 of http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dabraham/papers/abs07.pdf seems to prove the NP-hardness of finding a vertex-disjoint cycle cover of a directed graph, where each cycle has length at least three.

Comment: @RobinHouston the paper proofs the NP-hardness for directed cycles with lengths *at most* three because longer cycles would make no sense for kidney exchange, so the paper doesn't quite answer my question.

Comment: Since the graphs constructed in the proof have no 2-cycles, I think it does prove what you want, even if that’s not how it’s stated.

Comment: I think that [Gadgets, Approximation and Linear Programming](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.44.1673&rep=rep1&type=pdf) is sufficient for my purposes.